# How do I forward my Docker IP to the rest of the network?

Tags: docker, virtualbox, docker-machine

So I have a server running a dockerised instance of nextcloud and I can access it through a browser on the server. I would like to have it accessible on my whole LAN so I can port forward it and access it anywhere. I'm running docker with kitematic and virtualbox.

The IP where the server is running on is: 192.168.178.28

The IP with which I can access the docker instance on the server is: 192.168.99.100:32768

EDIT: The server is running on Windows Server 2016

Answer (score 1):

Since your service is running on a local IP address in Docker-Machine (from the looks of the IP address), you can use something like `nginx` to expose it to the rest of your network.

Install `nginx` and then update its configuration to forward from an external port to your dockerised app. On the Mac, you can install `nginx` using `brew install nginx` (if you have `homebrew` installed). For other operating systems, please check the [nginx documentation](https://nginx.org/en/).

The configuration for setting up a reverse proxy should look something like this:

```
http {
  server {
    # This is the external port
    listen 8080;
    access_log /usr/local/var/logs/nginx-rest-8080.access.log  main;

    location / {
      proxy_pass          http://192.168.99.100:8082/;
      proxy_set_header    Host $http_host;
    }
  }  
}
```

This will cause `nginx` to listen on port 8080 of your external IP address, and then forward all requests to your dockerised service, assuming that it's reachable on port 8082. Adjust as necessary...